# Advanced Fetching Alchemist I

Tags: mathematics, optimization, graph-theory, video-games

[image]

This follows the same rules as [previous Fetching Alchemist puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109534/fetching-alchemist-iii), except you choose where you start, and you may now return to your starting place after leaving it.

---

### How to Play

You are looking for the shortest possible path that allows you to complete all the quests. You choose where you start. The red numbers indicate the distance of each road. Present your answer in the form "99: ABCDE...", where the numbers are the total path distance and the letters are the place you started at followed by the places you visit on the path.

You complete a quest **by either starting there** or travelling there with the required items in your inventory, which are consumed upon completing the quest (if the quest has required items, indicated by the presence of items left of an arrow under the quest). <strike>Quests are not completed until you have travelled, so you don't complete quests by merely starting somewhere.</strike>

The items drawn around places are the reward items for the quests that can be completed there.

You can complete a quest more than once but only once per place.

You cannot avoid completing a quest that you are able to complete where you are. This includes when you have no need for the quest reward.

You can complete more than one quest in the same place. When completing more than one quest in the same place, quests are completed automatically from top to bottom. Consequently, completing a higher quest may prevent completing a lower quest.

If you would obtain an item from completing a quest, you can use it to complete a quest in the same place without travelling again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 36: IFDG

> There are not that many paths where you have both the winter reagent and the potion of nature near each other. The only other opportunity that I saw is "40: LJAI", which is longer.