# Fetching Alchemist IV

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, video-games

[image]

This is the fourth puzzle in the Fetching Alchemist series, and is another puzzle that is exclusive to Puzzling SE until solved.

This one might be a little too easy for those of you who have already solved one of these. I am working on making a difficult one.

Interesting fact: In the game, the ship can move directly from any planet to any other planet. This isn't possible in picture format unfortunately, where roads are limited to distances of 18 to ensure that they don't overlap, keeping the numbers clear.

---

### How to Play

You are looking for the shortest possible path that allows you to complete all the quests. The red numbers indicate the distance of each road. Present your answer in the form "99: ABCDE...", where the numbers are the total path distance and the letters are the places you visit on the path.

You complete a quest simply by travelling there with the required items in your inventory, which are consumed upon completing the quest (if the quest has required items, indicated by the presence of items left of an arrow under the quest).

The items drawn around places are the reward items for the quests that can be completed there.

You can complete a quest more than once but only once per place.

You cannot avoid completing a quest that you are able to complete where you are.

You can complete more than one quest in the same place. When completing more than one quest in the same place, quests are completed automatically from top to bottom. Consequently, completing a higher quest may prevent completing a lower quest.

If you would obtain an item from completing a quest, you can use it to complete a quest in the same place without travelling again.

You always start where the character is. You cannot return to the starting place once you have left. This is because, in the game, returning to the start is how you reset the puzzle.

If you are still unsure how to play, have a look at the [first solved puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109494/fetching-alchemist-i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 95: AKRNDFJ

> Since one needs to get 4×copper the upper left is mandatory. After that the only missing thing is lunar ore. J offers that and includes all upgrades.

Comment: Perfect, and great to see you here Arty :)